# Why Do I Have to Cast My Custom Adapter Object to a Class?

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview, casting, adapter

I am working on a simple Android app using Kotlin, and am currently implementing a custom subclass of `android.widget.BaseAdapter`. My class, `GridAdapter`, is associated with a `GridView`, which I have defined in my `activity_main.xml`. I attach it in my `MainActivity.kt` like so:

```
val gridView = findViewById<GridView>(R.id.gridView)
gridView.adapter = GridAdapter(applicationContext)
```

What I don't understand, is whenever I want to call one of that adapter's functions, I have to first cast it (a `GridAdapter` object) to a `GridAdapter` *class*, like so:

```
(gridView.adapter as GridAdapter).addImage(imageView)
```

This is despite the fact that `addImage` is not declared as static. Here's the method signature:

```
fun addImage(image: ImageView)
```

This seems to me like a non-sensical statement that would immediately cause a compilation error in any other scenario, and yet the Android Studio linter swears by it. Why? What's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `GridAdapter.adapter` has it return a generic `Adapter` because you can set it to any subtype of `Adapter`, due to the Liskov substitution principle of OOP.

The actual Adapter it is returning to you is a GridAdapter, since that is the subtype you passed to it earlier. But the compiler doesn’t know that. The compiler is incapable of figuring out that in this particular case, the Adapter being returned is specifically a GridAdapter. It is possible that the adapter has been changed to some other type in another function or by another thread, etc. The compiler can never be sophisticated enough to figure out something like this because it cannot run a whole simulation of the app every time you type a line of code so it can analyze and figure out all the possibilities.

So you cast it to tell the compiler that the `Adapter` is actually a `GridAdapter`. Remember that casting isn’t actually performing any conversion. It is only a promise you are making to the compiler that the variable you are working with is *already* the type you are claiming it is.

I’m not sure why you mention the function is not static. That would have nothing to do with casting.

Answer (score 0):

`GridView`'s adapter is a `ListAdapter` (inherited from `AbsListView`):

```
ListAdapter mAdapter;
```

Whenever you access `gridView.adapter` you'll get a `ListAdapter` not your `GridAdapter` from a compiler's perspective. Since you know that it's always a `GridAdapter` at runtime, you can cast it without risking a `ClassCastException`.

`addImage` seems to be a function in `GridAdapter` so the cast is needed to call that function. `ListAdapter` simply doesn't have that function.

Instead of casting each time, why don't you keep a reference to your `GridAdapter` and use that one instead? Like

```
val adapter = GridAdapter(applicationContext)
gridView.adapter = adapter
adapter.addImage(imageView)
```